# Why does this SDN4 query throw "The transaction has been terminated"?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

We use Spring Data Neo4j 4, and a very simple cypher

```
@Query("start a= node( {0} ) match a return id(a) as graphId,a.name as name,a.base as base")
List<NameBase> findNameByIds(@Param("0") List<Long> ids);
```

this exception often occurs , sometimes it's ok,and sometimes it throws this exception . Why is the transaction terminated?

```
org.neo4j.ogm.session.result.ResultProcessingException: "errors":[{"code":"Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure","message":"The transaction has been terminated.","stackTrace":"org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionTerminatedException: The transaction has been terminated.\n\tat org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.assertInUnterminatedTransaction(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:75)\n\tat org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.getTopLevelTransactionBoundToThisThread(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:104)\n\tat org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.getKernelTransactionBoundToThisThread(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:111)\n\tat org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.instance(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:64)\n\tat org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.planQuery(ExecutionEngine.scala:143)\n\tat org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:107)\n\tat org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:102)\n\tat org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.internal.ServerExecutionEngine.executeQuery(ServerExecutionEngine.java:61)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.executeStatements(TransactionHandle.java:327)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.commit(TransactionHandle.java:146)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.web.TransactionalService$2.write(TransactionalService.java:211)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:71)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:57)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.guard.GuardingRequestFilter.doFilter(GuardingRequestFilter.java:68)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)\n\tat ch.qos.logback.access.servlet.TeeFilter.doFilter(TeeFilter.java:55)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.guard.GuardingRequestFilter.doFilter(GuardingRequestFilter.java:68)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n"},{"code":"Neo.DatabaseError.Transaction.CouldNotRollback","message":"org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException: Transaction rolled back even if marked as successful","stackTrace":"java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException: Transaction rolled back even if marked as successful\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransitionalTxManagementKernelTransaction.rollback(TransitionalTxManagementKernelTransaction.java:69)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.closeContextAndCollectErrors(TransactionHandle.java:290)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.commit(TransactionHandle.java:147)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.web.TransactionalService$2.write(TransactionalService.java:211)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:71)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:57)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.guard.GuardingRequestFilter.doFilter(GuardingRequestFilter.java:68)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)\n\tat ch.qos.logback.access.servlet.TeeFilter.doFilter(TeeFilter.java:55)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.guard.GuardingRequestFilter.doFilter(GuardingRequestFilter.java:68)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\nCaused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException: Transaction rolled back even if marked as successful\n\tat org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.close(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:424)\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransitionalTxManagementKernelTransaction.rollback(TransitionalTxManagementKernelTransaction.java:65)\n\t... 39 more\n"}]}
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.JsonResponse.parseErrors(JsonResponse.java:165)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.JsonResponse.parseColumns(JsonResponse.java:139)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.JsonResponse.initialiseScan(JsonResponse.java:75)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.RowModelResponse.initialiseScan(RowModelResponse.java:63)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.RowModelResponse.<init>(RowModelResponse.java:37)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.request.SessionRequestHandler.execute(SessionRequestHandler.java:65)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery$1.apply(QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.java:65)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery$1.apply(QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.java:62)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.TransactionsDelegate.doInTransaction(TransactionsDelegate.java:54)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:422)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.mapToConcreteType(QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.java:62)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.execute(QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.java:52)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.execute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:50)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:454)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:432)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.findNameByIds(Unknown Source)
at com.xxx.service.neo4j.service.HumanService.humanRelatedCompany(HumanService.java:244)
at
```

Comment: Which version of SDN4 and neo4j-ogm? How many ids are supplied to that query?

Comment: neo4j-ogm-1.1.2 spring-data-neo4j-4.0.0.RELEASE

Comment: An issue around transactions was fixed in neo4j ogm 1.1.4-SNAPSHOT
Could you try this version? You'll need to include <repository>
            <id>neo4j-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

Comment: I change to 1.1.4-SNAPSHOT,and it my effects, thank you

Comment: in our online logs,we found this case also, whether it's a bug? our neo4j is 2.2.5 (https://github.com/tkroman/neo4j/commit/d9a127166a799c7d05ffe9852e4351694ced0531)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/80)- available in neo4j-ogm 1.1.4-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Hello,@Luanne ,  neo4j-ogm 1.1.4-SNAPSHOT also exist this problem. sdn4 only read, no writer,no update, how can I config trancaction ? whether this problem occurs while ids is too big,the transaction timeout, but the default transaction timeout is 60s. or whether in ha mode?